# django 'module' object has no attribute 'call_command'

Tags: python, django

I wrote a function like

```
def cmd_run(host="localhost", port="8000"):
    """Run server at given host port (or localhost 8000)"""
    from django.core import management
    host_port = '%s:%s' % (host, port)
    management.call_command('runserver', host_port)
```

When I executed it, an Exception was thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leona/workspace/bettyskitchen/lib/djangocliutils/bin/djangoctl", line 8, in <module> cli(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/leona/workspace/bettyskitchen/lib/djangocliutils/cmds.py", line 119, in  __call__ 
print method(*args) or ""
  File "/home/leona/workspace/bettyskitchen/lib/djangocliutils/cmds.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/leona/workspace/bettyskitchen/lib/djangocliutils/djangocmds/basic.py", line 19, in cmd_run
    management.call_command('runserver', host_port)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call_command'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here it works... maybe your version of django has not this function? Try it in managed shell `python manage.py shell` and try `help(management)` to see if it is there on your version.
Another possibility is corruption or modification of the `__init__.py` file (where call_command is defined) in `django.core.management` directory not importing the `call_command` function.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved, the django that I used was 0.96 not support call_command function, so I changed into :

```
def cmd_run(host="localhost", port="8000"):
    """Run server at given host port (or localhost 8000)"""
    from django.core import management
    management.runserver(host, port)
```

and this time it works!

Comment: I don't know your reasons behind using 0.96, but i suggest upgrading to newer version if possible.